# Pourquoi référendum ou péplum se terminent par /ɔm/ voir /œm/ et pas /um/ ?

Tags: prononciation, latin

J'ai une question qui me chiffonne un peu dont je ne vois pas vraiment d'où pourrait provenir l'origine : pourquoi est-ce que j'ai l'impression l'on prononce la fin de ces mots en *-um* (comme référendum ou péplum) `/ɔm/` voire `/œm/` ?

Si c'était un emprunt direct du latin, on devrait alors les prononcer `/um/` nan ?

- D'après ce que j'ai [lu sur Wikipédia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_spelling_and_pronunciation#Long_and_short_vowels), `/ɔ/` pouvait être prononcé pour un `/o/` court mais pas pour le `/u/`.
- Le `/œ/` n'existe quant à lui pas du tout en latin ([5<sup>e</sup> point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_French#Impact_of_substrate_and_superstrate_languages)).

Donc dernière possibilité, je me suis dit qu'il devait peut-être y avoir l'influence de la prononciation anglaise partiellement francisée (`/ˌrefəˈrendəm/` selon [wordrefererence](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rendum)).

Si quelqu'un a une explication, je suis preneur :)

---

This question bothers me, and I don't really have an explanation of where this may come from: why do I have the impression that words which end with *-um* (as *référendum* or *péplum*) are pronounced (in French) `/ɔm/` or else `/œm/` ?

If it is a direct loan from Latin, shouldn't we say `/um/` ?

- According to what I [read on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_spelling_and_pronunciation#Long_and_short_vowels), `/ɔ/` could be said for a short `/o/` but not for the short `/u/`.
- `/œ/` doesn't exist at all in Latin ([5<sup>th</sup> point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_French#Impact_of_substrate_and_superstrate_languages)).

So last possibility, I think it may come from an English pronunciation then frenchified (`/ˌrefəˈrendəm/` according to [wordrefererence](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rendum)).

If anyone has any explanation, please share it :)

Comment: Je n'ai pas de réponse absolue, mais il est bon de noter que la prononciation du latin a fait l'objet de maints débats (particulièrement en France, où l'omniprésence du Latin d'Église complique les choses): pour s'en rendre compte, il suffit de comparer la prononciation qui était enseignée il y a 30 ans et celle (dite "restituée", je crois) qui est couramment utilisée maintenant. La prononciation en /œ/ provient sans doute de la prononciation latine "non-restituée" (donc, en gros, du latin d'Église)...

Comment: @Dave Pas besoin d'*avoir une réponse absolue* pour rédiger une réponse. Les éléments que tu apportes sont utiles, comme le soulignent les votes. L'intéressante réponse de Pascal Qvy n'est pas non plus absolue ni définitive, et cela ne pose pas de problème, au contraire.

Comment: @RomainVALERI: noté. Et puisque personne ne semble avoir proposé de réponse plus définitive, j'ai déménagé mon commentaire en réponse...

Answer (score 9):

Les mots en `-um` se prononcent comme en latin : [-ɔm]. *Album*, *laudanum*, *aquarium*, *calcium*, référendum, etc. riment avec *petit bonhomme*, *baba au rhum*, *tarte aux pommes*, *métronome*, etc. L'anglais n'a rien à voir dans l'affaire ; à l'époque où la prononciation actuelle s'est stabilisée, les mots passaient la Manche dans l'autre sens.

Le latin, oui, mais quel latin ? Il s'agit du latin tel que prononcé par les Français de la Renaissance au milieu du 20<sup>e</sup> siècle. La prononciation du latin a évolué au fil des siècles et des lieux. Déjà, lorsque le latin était la langue vivante d'une population et une langue d'échange au delà, il en a existé de nombreuses variantes et de nombreux accents. Au Moyen Âge, même si le latin était la langue commune (on dira plus tard, la *lingua franca*) des savants, sa prononciation a été influencée par celle de la langue vernaculaire (la vulgate) dans chaque pays. Les Italiens, les Français, les Espagnols, les Anglais, etc. ont chacun prononcé le latin avec leur accent. L'Église catholique a été un facteur d'unification pour la langue latine, avec le [latin ecclésiastique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_eccl%C3%A9siastique) donc la prononciation se rapproche de la prononciation italienne, mais même au sein de l'Église la prononciation n'est pas uniforme et a évolué dans le temps. De nos jours, il y a une tendance internationale à converger vers une [prononciation restituée](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin#Prononciation_ancienne_restitu.C3.A9e).

On connaît la prononciation des époques passées quelquefois grâce aux textes de contemporains, mais surtout grâce aux chants. Le rythme indique quelles syllabes peuvent être longues ou accentuées et les rimes donnent beaucoup d'indications sur le son que représente telle ou telle lettre.

Au Moyen Âge, en France, la prononciation du latin était fortement influencée par la prononciation du français. En particulier, le `n` ou le `m` après une voyelle avait tendance à rendre cette voyelle nasale. C'est ainsi qu'un mot latin comme *dictum* a pu devenir le français *[dicton](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/dicton)*. Un *album* (papier blanc) ressemblait donc beaucoup à *Albion* (terre aux falaises blanches). D'autres pays avaient leurs spécificités ; ainsi *centum* se prononçais [sɛ̃.tɔ̃] en France mais [tʃɛn.tum] en Italie.

Autour du 16<sup>e</sup> siècle, la prononciation du `-um` en finale a évolué en [ɔm]. Cela a permis par exemple à Molière de faire rimer *ignorantum* avec « ignorant homme » dans [*Le Malade imaginaire*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Malade_imaginaire) (1673). Son contemporain Charpentier a écrit un [*Te Deum*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Te_Deum_(Charpentier)) qu'il disait [te.de.ɔm]. C'est cette prononciation, que Marouzeau décrit comme « un compromis entre un latin mort et un français désuet », qui a donné la prononciation actuelle des mots en `-um` en français.

De nos jours, on enseigne en Françe et ailleurs la prononciation restituée du latin, dans laquelle `-um` se prononce [um]. Si l'on importait un mot latin aujourd'hui, il se défendrait de le prononcer [-um] comme meilleure approximation d'un emprunt direct, mais [-ɔm] serait plus cohérent pour suivre les habitudes existantes. Pour les mots qui sont français depuis plus d'un siècle, la prononciation a toujours été [-ɔm] depuis que le mot est français, ou au moins depuis plusieurs siècles, donc il n'y a aucune raison de prononcer [-um]. Et pour les mots récents en `-um` comme les éléments chimiques (uranium, röntgenium, ...), qui ne viennent pas du latin, on prononce [-ɔm], en suivant la règle qui veut que la finale `-um` se prononce [-ɔm].

Même *rhum* et *bégum* se prononcent [-ɔm], mais dans ces deux cas, contrairement à celui des mots d'origine latine ou aux mots calqués sur des mots latins, c'est certainement l'influence de l'anglais qui se manifeste.

#### Références

- Philippe Cibois. *La prononciation du latin*. [1. l'enseignement](http://enseignement-latin.hypotheses.org/4209) ; [2. le chant](http://enseignement-latin.hypotheses.org/4259) ; [3. Érasme](http://enseignement-latin.hypotheses.org/4289).
- René Gosciny. *Astérix en Corse*. Voir aussi [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_camps_romains_d%27Ast%C3%A9rix_le_Gaulois).
- Charles-François Lhomond. *Elémens de grammaire latine* (1779, 1903).
- Jules Marouzeau. *La prononciation du latin (histoire, théorie, pratique)* (1931, 1955).
- Jacques Poitou. [*Écriture et prononciation du latin classique*.](http://j.poitou.free.fr/pro/html/ltn/latin.html)
- Patricia M. Ranum. *Méthode de la prononciation latine dite vulgaire ou à la française. Petite méthode à l’usage des chanteurs et des récitants d’après le manuscrit de Dom Jacques Le Clerc* (1991).

Comment: Maudit que c'est bon cette réponse-là. Merci !

Answer (score 3):

Le français est moins une langue latine qu'elle n'y parait, et relève plus de la « [langue romane rustique](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoire_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise#La_substance_du_superstrat_francique) ».

Il puise ses sources dans [les langues d'oïl](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langue_d%27o%C3%AFl), un groupe de [langues romanes](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langues_romanes) dans lequel le latin n'est plus qu'une sorte de [pidgin](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidgin), bref, l'ombre de lui même…

Ceci pourrait expliquer ce problème de prononciation.

Comment: +1 pour les liens et l'ouverture de l'éventail des solutions possibles

Answer (score 3):

*[commentaire reposté en réponse:]*

Je n'ai pas de réponse absolue, mais il est bon de noter que la prononciation du latin a fait l'objet de maints débats (particulièrement en France, où l'omniprésence du Latin d'Église complique les choses): pour s'en rendre compte, il suffit de comparer la prononciation qui était enseignée il y a 30 ans et celle (dite "restituée", je crois) qui est couramment utilisée maintenant.

La prononciation en /œ/ provient sans doute de la prononciation latine "non-restituée" (donc, en gros, du latin d'Église)...