# Words which <u> sound open-mid back rounded vowel

Tags: orthographe

In the word « forum » letter "u" sounds [ɔ]. is any‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌ other word which letter 
 "u" sound [ɔ] in French or this word is an exception?

Comment: Basically all words that end in *-um*. Here is a related question https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/.

Comment: except *parfum*.

Comment: There's also *summum*, who extends the /ɔ pronunciation to a non final syllable: /sɔmːɔm/ or /sɔmɔm/

Comment: hum, hum, hum...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most words ending in `-um` are words derived from an identically-spelled Latin word. They have kept their “Latin” pronunciation, at least for the ending. This is not the way the Romans pronounced, or even a Late Latin pronunciation, but the way French scholars pronounced Latin from the Renaissance to the 20th century.

Any word that ends with the suffix `-um` and is either derived from Latin (even indirectly) or constructed in the same way is pronounced [-ɔm]. This includes a number of everyday words such as *album*, *aquarium*, *minimum*, *maximum*, etc. This applies even if the spelling of the word has been adapted, for example to add an acute accent on `e` when pronounced [e], as in *référendum*, *sérum*, ... This also includes modern words constructed on the same model, such as the name of most chemical elements (*hélium*, *uranium*, *röntgenium*, ...) and other words such as *extrêmum*, *millénium*, ...

Even words that are not derived from Latin end but end in `-um` may be pronounced [-ɔm] by contagion, for example *[bégum](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/b%C3%A9gum)* (which French people know from the [Jules Verne novel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Cinq_Cents_Millions_de_la_B%C3%A9gum)), *rhum* (pronounced just like *Rome*).

There are only a few exceptions. The main one is *parfum*: this word is derived from Latin, but `-um` is part of the root, not a suffix, so it's pronounced normally, i.e. the `m` turns the `u` into a nasal: [paʁfœ̃]. Words that end in `-oum` are pronounced [-um]. The onomatopoeia *hum* denotes a sound that is closer to [hœm] or something like [xm], with a throat clearing followed by a long [m] without anything in between that French phonetics identifies as a vowel.

For more information about the history of the pronunciation of the final `-um` in French, see [Pourquoi référendum ou péplum se terminent par /ɔm/ voir /œm/ et pas /um/ ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/pourquoi-r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rendum-ou-p%C3%A9plum-se-terminent-par-%C9%94m-voir-%C5%93m-et-pas-um)