# Prononciation de « spécimen » : pourquoi pas le son nasal ?

Tags: prononciation, nasalisation

Pourquoi le mot *spécimen* se prononce [spesimɛn] et pas [spesimɛ̃] ? Je me demande pourquoi le son nasal [ɛ̃] disparaît.

Par exemple « paysan » , « européen », etc., gardent le son nasal et le perdent lorsqu'on rajoute la déclinaison féminine (« paysanne », « européenne », etc.).

Je sais que les règles de nasalisation ne sont pas respectées avec les noms propres (par exemple, « Kevin ») mais *spécimen* n'est pas un nom propre.

La seule explication que je peux donner c'est que le mot français vient de l'anglais. C'est bizarre quand même car le mot a une origine latine.

Comment: Worth noting is the nasal sound is not what disappears, historically speaking. The /n/ disappears and leaves a nasalized vowel. The question is thus why this word *didn't* lose its final consonant like the others, and the answer that it was borrowed from English is satisfactory. Don't forget that many words in Latinate languages were re-borrowed from Latin later on, the original words having been lost or even coexisting but under an unrecognizably changed form. And sometimes this later borrowing was indirect, French speakers and English speakers both being far from classical Latin by then. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Selon le TLFi:

> Les finales graph. voyelle + n notent gén. une voyelle nasale à l'exception de -en prononcé [εn] : *abdomen, cyclamen, lichen.* Cependant, on prononce [ε ̃] dans *examen* (cf. Fouché Prononc. 1959, p. 385).

([abdomen](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/abdomen))

La prononciation en français de mots latins n'est pas toujours la même que celle de mots français. Voir aussi [*-um* = /ɔm/](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/pourquoi-r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rendum-ou-p%C3%A9plum-se-terminent-par-%C9%94m-voir-%C5%93m-et-pas-um) dans *album,* et les autres exemples dans le document "[Pourquoi prononcer le latin « à la française » ?](http://om-editions.e-monsite.com/medias/files/prononcer-le-latin-3.pdf)"

Answer (score 6):

Le TLFi [indique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/specimen) que le mot est entré dans le dictionnaire de l’Académie en 1835, qui mentionnait alors...

> On prononce, au singulier et au pluriel, *spécimène* (en 1935, *spécimenne*)

On mentionne aussi que le mot a été emprunté à l’anglais dès 1610, qui l’avait emprunté du latin *specimen* « indice, exemple, échantillon, exemplaire, type ».

Que l’anglais n’ait pas nasalisé est naturel. Que le français ait emprunté la prononciation anglaise, somme toute assez proche d’une prononciation française naturelle, cela n’est pas inusité.

Il y a eu francisation partielle de l’orthographe, qui a acquis un accent aigu sur le premier E, mais la terminaison est demeurée identique. Pas d’ajout de lettre, donc, mais ajout d’accent néanmoins. Cela lui donne peut-être un petit air exotique dans le panorama francophone d’aujourd’hui.

Comment: @jlliagre Peut-être est-ce une utilisation impropre du terme *inusité*, mais inattendu n'est pas ce que j'avais en tête. Je désirais indiquer que ce cas n'est pas unique. J'attends votre opinion sur la chose, et ajusterai en fonction.

Comment: Pas une utilisation impropre, le sens *inhabituel* étant attesté, mais dans ce contexte une utilisation inattendue du terme inusité ;-) En linguistique, *inusité* s'applique à un mot ou une expression. *Cela n'a rien d'inhabituel* ou *cela n'a rien d'unique* pourrait aller, mais *inusité* peut être laissé tel quel. J'étais d'ailleurs en train de le rétablir mais tu as, pardon vous avez été plus rapide. Quant à l'orthographe de *specimen*, elle a été francisée par l'ajout d'un accent aigu. La prononciation de *spécimen* est régulière en français, c'est celle d' *examen* qui ne l'est pas.

Comment: C'est vrai, je corrige