# Prononciation des mots en -um

Tags: prononciation, latin

On m’a fait remarquer, après toute une vie de pratique du français comme langue maternelle, que ma prononciation des mots en -um tels que *maximum*, *forum*, *album*, etc. était incorrecte. Je prononçais la dernière voyelle comme dans *œuf*, et la prononciation officielle semble être comme dans *somme*. J’ai d’ailleurs été très surpris de ne jamais avoir repéré l’erreur moi-même en remarquant que je ne prononçais pas comme les autres ; je crois que j’ai l’impression d’avoir toujours entendu les autres prononcer de ma façon, jusqu’à ce qu’on relève ma faute.

Je n’ai aucune idée de l’origine de mon erreur. Est-ce que cela a toujours été ainsi ? Puis-je avoir imité cette prononciation en entendant une personne âgée qui l’aurait apprise à une époque où elle était correcte ? Ou ai-je été toute ma vie victime d’une illusion auditive ?

Comment: Il existe bien le mot *hum* qui se prononce à ma connaissance toujours de cette façon (/œm/), mais c'est le seul. Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/pourquoi-r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rendum-ou-p%C3%A9plum-se-terminent-par-%C9%94m-voir-%C5%93m-et-pas-um où cette prononciation n'est pas écartée dans la question.

Answer (score 1):

J'ai longtemps fait la même erreur. Surtout avec le mot "forum", que je croisait plus souvent à l'écrit qu'à l'oral.

À mon avis, aucune hallucination auditive de ta part (ni de la mienne), une simple "mauvaise logique" dans le déchiffrement desdits mot, jusqu'à ce que l'on te le fasse remarquer.
Je pense que comme le `œ` est phonétiquement plus "proche" que `o` de la prononciation de la lettre `u`, nous avons instinctivement fait cette erreur, voilà tout :).

Comment: H(e)um, tu veux dire que c'est un peu comme si on ressentait une contradiction entre la lecture "u" et le son "o", et qu'on "résout" cette contradiction en entendant "œ" ? C'est intéressant et maintenant que tu m'y fais penser, ça me parle un peu, oui !

Comment: Est-ce qu'on peut totalement écarter la possibilité d'une tentative inconsciente d'imiter la prononciation anglaise?  Ce sont des mots de caractère international.  En apprenant le Français, j"ai noté bien cette prononciation surprenante de la terminaison "um" comme si l'écriture ait été "omme."